# Graph Theory: Prove this group of people can be divided into two groups

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

> In a party each person has at most 3 friends. Prove that people in the
>   party can be divided into two groups, such that each person has at
>   most one friend in his group.

Any idea how to start the proof?

Comment: Start with a proper 3-colouring of the graph, then recolour the vertices of one colour class. Deal with $K_4$ separately.

Comment: @bof you are correct, my implied procedure does not work. I will refrain from hasty posting early in the day in the future!

Comment: @GordonRoyle What if you just take a $2$ -colouring which minimizes the number of adjacent pairs of the same colour? That works, doesn't it?

Comment: @bof yes, if there is a vertex with more than one same-colour neighbour then switching its colour will decrease the number of monochromatic edges.